# Moment of a force about a given axis

Tags: vectors, torque

I have learnt in class about finding the moment of a force **F** about a point A using the formula

> **M** = **r** × **F**
>
> where **r** is the vector directed from A to the point of origin of **F**

A textbook problem requires me to find the moment of a force about an axis. I had a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bending_moment#Computing_the_moment_of_force and found another formula:

> **M** = **e** · (**r** × **F**)

However, now I cannot understand what **r** to take in this formula. The problem in my textbook requires me to find the moment of a force of 276.85N directed from (8,-3,0) to (0,0,6) along an axis directed from (12,0,0) to (0,4,-6). The answer provided is 1000Nm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the page you cite:

> r is the position vector from the reference point (O) to the point of application of the force (A).

In other words, **r** is the vector joining a point of the axis of rotation, and the point where the force is applied.

The vector **e** is a unit vector of the rotation axis. Projecting on **e**, as done in your second formula, ensures you can take any reference point (O) on the rotation axis, and still obtain the same result.